# Preference in choosing SODIUM or POTASSIum hydroxide in nucleophilic substitution of haloalkanes

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, hydroxides

When you substitute a halogenated alkane to form alcohol, why is it with reagents like NaOH or KOH? I understand the need for the OH hydroxide bit, but I am not sure why you need the Na cation or K cation. Can't you use some other cation? It seems to me that use of these cations will react with the halogen atom to produce a soluble ionic product. Is this a desirable outcome? And why?

Comment: What other source of OH- would you propose using? If you want OH- acting as nucleophile you need a cation

Comment: $\ce{OH-}$ ions do not exist alone. They must be accompanied by a cation, like $\ce{Na+}$ or $\ce{K+}$. But of course, another cation can be used, like $\ce{Ba^{2+}}$ or $\ce{Ca^{2+}}$, provided its hydroxide is sufficiently soluble in water.

Comment: Perhaps the question should be rephrased Does Na+ or K+ make a difference as the title suggests.  Yes the cation can make a profound difference depending on the reaction.

Comment: OH- doesn't exist on its own. I like to think of the Na+ and K+ as “carriers.” But like @jimchmst said, the way a reaction proceeds can depend on the action.

Comment: Any reason for writing element names in all capitals?